# Double string comparison fails with correct String reporting

Tags: bash, if-statement

So simple and so not working at the same time..

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

RES=$(tail -1 $1)
VAR2=$(grep -oh $2 $1 | tail -1)
VAR3=$(grep -oh $3 $1 | tail -1)

#echo "res=${RES} | var2=${VAR2} - var3=${VAR3}"
#exit 0

if [ ! -f $1 ]; then
  echo "Log file not found"
  exit 3
else
  if [[ ${RES} == ${VAR2}  &&  ${RES} != ${VAR3} ]]; then
    echo $RES
    exit 0
  fi
  if [[ ${RES} == ${VAR2}  &&  ${RES} == ${VAR3} ]]; then
    echo $RES
    exit 1
  fi
  if [[ ${RES} != ${VAR2}  &&  ${RES} == ${VAR3} ]]; then
    echo $RES
    exit 2
  fi
  echo $RES
  exit 3
fi
```

This is a nagios script that helps me to read log files.
I call this script (from nagios) with `/usr/local/.../read_log.sh OK NOK`

If I uncomment

```
#echo "res=${RES} | var2=${VAR2} - var3=${VAR3}"
#exit 0
```

I see from Nagios

```
Status Information: res=Backup of Monday: OK: Backup of CURRENT: NOK
Performance Data:   var2=OK - var3=NOK
```

Which should be the 2nd IF with exit 1. But it won't and no matter what, it always go for `Unable to read output` both if log contain OK and/OR NOK

**EDIT:**
Using this code:

```
  if [[ ${RES} =~ ^.*:.${VAR2}.*$ ]] && [[ ! ${RES} =~ ^.*:.${VAR3}.*$ ]]; then
    echo "$RES exit 0"
    exit 0
  fi
  if [[ ${RES} =~ ^.*:.${VAR2}.*$ ]] && [[ ${RES} =~ ^.*:.${VAR3}.*$ ]]; then
    echo "$RES exit 1"
    exit 1
  fi
  if [[ ! ${RES} =~ ^.*:.${VAR2}.*$ ]] && [[ ! ${RES} =~ ^.*:.${VAR3}.*$ ]]; then
    echo "$RES exit 2"
    exit 2
  fi
```

Output is:

```
user@server:/usr/local/nagios/libexec# ./read_last_line.sh /var/log/Samba_backup.log OK error
Backup of Monday: OK - Backup of CURRENT: OK exit 1
```

**EDIT 3:**
Alright I found something interesting. When $RES contains only OK, $VAR3 is "", empty.

Before the main if I added:

```
if [ -z $VAR3 ]; then
  VAR3=error
fi
```

And the script `exit 1` when it find "error" and `exit 0` when there is OK.
I think I'll just clean it and write it better. If someone can post the complete code with the condition where $VAR="" I'll set this question as solved!

**EDIT 4:**
And, to match every cases, this is the complete code with correction from EDIT 3 to $VAR2 too:

```
if [ ! -f $1 ]; then
  echo "Log file not found"
  exit 3
else
  if [[ ${RES} =~ ^.*:.${VAR2}.*$ ]] && [[ ! ${RES} =~ ^.*:.${VAR3}.*$ ]]; then
    echo $RES
    exit 0
  fi
  if [[ ${RES} =~ ^.*:.${VAR2}.*$ ]] && [[ ${RES} =~ ^.*:.${VAR3}.*$ ]]; then
    echo $RES
    exit 1
  fi
  if [[ ! ${RES} =~ ^.*:.${VAR2}.*$ ]] && [[ ${RES} =~ ^.*:.${VAR3}.*$ ]]; then
    echo $RES
    exit 2
  fi
  if [[ ! ${RES} =~ ^.*:.${VAR2}.*$ ]] && [[ ! ${RES} =~ ^.*:.${VAR3}.*$ ]]; then
    echo $RES
    exit 2
  fi
  echo $RES
  exit 3
fi
```

**EDIT 5: This should be the last version, revisioned from the original and latest code from (and thanks to) @jgshawkey**

```
RES=$(tail -1 $1)
VAR2=$(grep -oh $2 $1 | tail -1)
VAR3=$(grep -oh $3 $1 | tail -1)

[[ -z ${VAR2} ]] && VAR2=$2
[[ -z ${VAR3} ]] && VAR3=$3


# if $VAR2 exists
if [[ $(echo ${RES} | egrep "$VAR2") ]]; then
  # and if $VAR3 does not exist
  if [[ ! $(echo ${RES} | egrep "$VAR3") ]]; then
    echo ${RES}
    exit 0
  # and if $VAR3 exists too
  elif [[ $(echo ${RES} | egrep "$VAR3") ]]; then
    echo ${RES}
    exit 1
  fi
# else if $VAR2 does not exist
else
  # and if $VAR3 does not exists
  if [[ ! $(echo ${RES} | egrep "$VAR3") ]]; then
    echo ${RES}
    exit 1
  # and if $VAR3 exists too
  elif [[ $(echo ${RES} | egrep "$VAR3") ]]; then
    echo ${RES}
    exit 2
  fi
fi
```

Comment: you have it because string "RES" contains both OK and NOK so it goes to proper if statement and return 0.

Comment: Yeah that's right.. I'm now using "error" instead of "NOK", I do not want to mix the words. I'm using your suggestion but you won't believe it still reports Warning when there is only OK. If there's "error" it reports Warning too, but in this case it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking to match the words "OK" and "NOK" against a longer string.  To put it into perspective:

"Backup of Monday: OK: Backup of CURRENT: NOK" does not equal "OK" or "NOK".  You are wanting to do a search for a pattern within a string.  See the revised code below.  This will look for "*: OK*" or "*: NOK*" within the string $RES.

I hope this helps.

```
if [ ! -f $1 ]; then
  echo "Log file not found"
  exit 3
else
  if [[ ${RES} =~ ^.*:.${VAR2}.*$ ]] && [[ ! ${RES} =~ ^.*:.${VAR3}.*$ ]]; then
    echo $RES
    exit 0
  fi
  if [[ ${RES} =~ ^.*:.${VAR2}.*$ ]] && [[ ${RES} =~ ^.*:.${VAR3}.*$ ]]; then
    echo $RES
    exit 1
  fi
 if [[ ! ${RES} =~ ^.*:.${VAR2}.*$ ]] && [[ ! ${RES} =~ ^.*:.${VAR3}.*$ ]]; then
    echo $RES
    exit 2
  fi
  echo $RES
  exit 3
fi
```

**- EDIT**

Are VAR2 and VAR3 pulling from $RES or from another source?
What all can VAR2 and VAR3 be set to?  So far I have seen: VAR2 and VAR3 equal to "", OK, or NOK.
What all can RES be set to?
Once I know what we are dealing with we can work around the rest.

```
# assumptions
# RES is something like "Backup of Monday: OK: Backup of CURRENT: NOK"
# VAR2 is "OK" or ""
# VAR3 is "OK" or ""

# if $VAR2|$VAR3 are blank set them to "OK"
[[ -z ${VAR2} ]] && VAR2="OK"
[[ -z ${VAR3} ]] && VAR2="OK"

# if file does not exist exit 3
[[ ! -f $1 ]] && echo "Log file not found" && exit 3

[[ ${RES} =~ ^.*:.${VAR2}.*$ ]] && [[ ! ${RES} =~ ^.*:.${VAR3}.*$ ]] && echo ${RES} && exit 0
[[ ${RES} =~ ^.*:.${VAR2}.*$ ]] && [[ ${RES} =~ ^.*:.${VAR3}.*$ ]] && echo ${RES} && exit 1
[[ ! ${RES} =~ ^.*:.${VAR2}.*$ ]] && [[ ! ${RES} =~ ^.*:.${VAR3}.*$ ]] && echo ${RES} && exit 2
```

**- EDIT**

Let's make this even easier.

You can use multiple search items in the declaration of VAR2 and VAR3.
For instance: VAR2="^$|OK".  This will match on a blank line or the word "error".
This should be easier to script for.

```
RES=$(tail -1 $1)
VAR2=$(grep -oh $2 $1 | tail -1)
VAR3=$(grep -oh $3 $1 | tail -1)

[[ -z ${VAR2} ]] && VAR2="OK"
[[ -z ${VAR3} ]] && VAR3="OK"


# if $VAR2 okay
if [[ $(echo ${RES} | egrep "$VAR2") ]]; then
  # and if $VAR3 not okay
  if [[ ! $(echo ${RES} | egrep "$VAR3") ]]; then
    echo ${RES}
    exit 0
  # and if $VAR3 okay
  elif [[ $(echo ${RES} | egrep "$VAR3") ]]; then
    echo ${RES}
    exit 1
  fi
# else if $VAR2 not okay
elif [[ ! $(echo ${RES} | egrep "$VAR2") ]]; then
  # and if $VAR3 not okay
  if [[ ! $(echo ${RES} | egrep "$VAR3") ]]; then
    echo ${RES}
    exit 2
  fi
```

Comment: Wow! nice pattern matching! Still, I get Warning when $RES contains only OK. :-/

Comment: What kind of warning you're talking about and what is you're exit status?

Comment: The pattern matching is based on the $RES string you provided.  It looks for, specifically:
 - ^ beginning of line
 - .* anything up to...
 - : a colon
 - . any character after the colon (space in this case)
 - ${VAR2} the search string
 - .* anything after the search string

This should match "exit 1".  Please provide the exact output you're getting.

Comment: The output didn't change for all of the codes used, if `Backup of Monday: OK - Backup of CURRENT: error` Nagios exit with Warning.
If `Backup of Monday: OK - Backup of CURRENT: OK` The Warning is still there. 

I'm reading the documentations you all guys provided me and also avoiding " " inside [[ ]] But still I am not able to see it running properly :/

I'm quite sure yours codes are good but really the Warning is always around the corner

Comment: exit status is 1 (Warning for Nagios) both for OK - error and OK - OK

Comment: @jgshawkey I think I found something: When $RES does not contain "error", $VAR3 is "". empty.
I think it always exits with 1 because can't match "". I'm thinking of a way to fix this

Comment: @Nihvel, see additional edits in the answer above and let me know any additional information.

Comment: @jgshawkey wonderful! that's really a good job and clean code! going to try it asap ;)

Comment: @jgshawkey I've got some doubts about it: `[[ -z ${VAR3} ]] && VAR3="OK"` shouldn't this be "error" and, I prefer to not touch the code. I want it to have the VARs I pass to the script. I'd re-write as `[[ -z ${VAR3} ]] && VAR3="$3"`

And: the second ELIF should match the same cases of the main IF. `IF !VAR2 && VAR3 -> exit 2` (because var2=error - var3=error).
`IF !VAR2 && !VAR3 -> exit 1` (because var2=error - var3=OK).

Comment: Hi @Nihvel, I was basing the `[[ -z ${VAR3} ]] && VAR3="OK"` off of your previous statement that $VAR3 is empty if $RES does not contain "error".  The assumption here was that if it didn't contain "error" it was blank and therefore "OK".

Comment: `VAR3=$(grep -oh $3 $1 | tail -1)` already sets $VAR3 to $3, but if it is not set then `[[ -z ${VAR3} ]] && VAR3="OK"` will set it to "OK".  We can change this based on what the possible contents of $3 can be.

Comment: You should post what all possible values $RES, $VAR2, and $VAR3 can be set to and whether those values are considered good or bad.  That'll help with the logic.

Comment: @jgshawkey Hi so thank you for still working on this! Well, to have two different VARs with same value (OK) forced from the script, it is not what I wanted. The script (called by nagios) must ask for a good value and a bad one. Therefore I prefer to keep using "OK" and "error". Just my preference, but this way I read the code better, because when VAR3 is empty I know that the LogFile does not contain that word, so I force "error" to not be Grep'ed and generate exit 0. Anyway mate, your code helped me a lot!

Comment: No problem at all.  Good luck to you!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the comparison is wrong because your `RES` variable is equal to `Backup of Monday: OK: Backup of CURRENT: NOK` and `VAR2` equals `OK` so how are you searching for it?

I think you should use:

```
if [ "${RES}" != *"NOK"* ] ; then
```

to make sure that NOK is not available.

As @chepner pointed in a comment:
you can use either notation above or use double square brackets and omit the quotation marks (`"`).

See [HERE](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) and [HERE](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) for reference.

Comment: This was a case I didn't try but the result is the same unfortunately. And running this command from terminal does not change, no output. +1 for the link and answer anyway, thank you!

Comment: Try using `-eq` instead of `==`

Comment: isn't -eq for numbers comparison? Won't work. BUT I guess I found the error. Not able to fix tho. I'm updating the main question ;)

Comment: I just read your comment! Seems we're close. Thank you I'm checking it!

Comment: Quoting single parameter expansions inside `[[...]]` is unnecessary.